# How to select different element of different row in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Lst's say there is a matrix A

```
A = [[ 34 61 29 74(17)32 72 92 93 57 ]
     [(46)10 23 84 74 57 56 88 90 36 ]
     [ 23(83)58 42 93 54 82 48 63 73 ]]
```

and a vector b of size 3
`b = [4, 0, 1]`

Does numpy has any function that would do the following job?

```
>>>A.choose_row_wise(b)
would output:
[17, 46, 83]
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using indexing.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[34, 61, 29, 74, 17, 32, 72, 92, 93, 57],[46, 10, 23, 84, 74, 57, 56, 88, 90, 36],[23, 83, 58, 42, 93, 54, 82, 48, 63, 73]])
b = np.array([4, 0, 1])
result = A[np.arange(len(b)), b]
```

```
[17 46 83]
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`numpy.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html):

```
b = np.array([4, 0, 1])
res = np.take_along_axis(A, b[:, None], axis=1).flatten()
print(res)
```

---

```
[17 46 83]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[34,61,29,74,(17),32,72,92,93,57],[(46),10,23,84,74,57,56,88,90,36],[23,(83),58,42,93,54,82,48,63,73]])
b = [4, 0, 1]

print([A[b.index(i), i] for i in b])
```